# Prevent git bash automatically change the path

Tags: git, path, git-bash

When I run some code in git bash, I found the path was changed automatically.

```
$ python src/loon/skeleton.py  upload ~/test.R /tmp -v
[2019-11-03 10:41:07] INFO:__main__:Starting loon...
[2019-11-03 10:41:07] INFO:__main__:Upload command is detected.
=> Starting upload...

[2019-11-03 10:41:07] INFO:__main__:Running scp -pr -P 22 C:/Users/Administrator/test.R wangshx@10.15.22.110:C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/
scp: C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/: No such file or directory
[2019-11-03 10:41:08] INFO:__main__:Status code: 1
Error: an error occurred, please check the info!
```

`/tmp` here is a path on remote host. You can see `/tmp` is changed to `C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/`. I can't prevent it by either add `'` or `"`.

```
$ python src/loon/skeleton.py  upload ~/test.R '/tmp' -v
[2019-11-03 10:43:17] INFO:__main__:Starting loon...
[2019-11-03 10:43:17] INFO:__main__:Upload command is detected.
=> Starting upload...

[2019-11-03 10:43:17] INFO:__main__:Running scp -pr -P 22 C:/Users/Administrator/test.R wangshx@10.15.22.110:C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/
scp: C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/: No such file or directory
[2019-11-03 10:43:19] INFO:__main__:Status code: 1
Error: an error occurred, please check the info!
```

Comment: Is this really a bash problem? Because I think that's output coming out of a python script so I think you should go check what the python script is doing. The most that bash is probably doing is expanding ~ into your users's home directory, other than that the python script is doing the other path calculations.

Comment: @eftshift0 Yes. I used argparse module to process arguments and it will not change the path. The program works in windows terminal but  git bash.

Answer (score 8):

This is because Git-Bash is trying to be helpful and converting Linux looking paths to their Windows equivalent.

If you add `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` to the beginning of your command, it will tell git-bash to not replace `/tmp` with your `Temp` directory.
Your command will look like this:

`MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 python src/loon/skeleton.py  upload ~/test.R /tmp -v`

The solution is based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61907994/git-bash-confuse-with-slash-when-running-bash-script-on-windows).

Comment: Yeah, the problem is it's broken: today I had to debug way too long because of it "adjusting" `C:/sz/prj/Space_Test/test/tmp` to `C:\sz\prj\Space_Test\test\C:\Program Files\Git\sz\prj\Space_Test\test\tmp\` :) _[Sorry, it seems the markdown parser can't cope with the second path, oh well... But you get the idea.]_

Comment: _[Jeez, had to put this into a separate comment, otherwise all of it got rendered as `code` after that prior botched path...]_ Mind you, also its idea of `/tmp` being that dir comes from a "random" prj-specific var called `TMP_DIR`. I'm not sure how "standard" that is, so, who knows what else would it "helpfully" pick up if not kept on leash?