# Git Bash confuse with Slash '/' when running bash script on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, shell, git-bash, slash

How can I run bash script on git bash with slash '/' on Windows.

Here is my script file. I can run well on Ubuntu/Linux.

```
#!/bin/sh

KONG_ADMIN_HOST=localhost
KONG_ADMIN_PORT=8001

registerServiceRoute() {
  printf "\nRegister %s service route\n" $1
  curl -XPOST ${KONG_ADMIN_HOST}:${KONG_ADMIN_PORT}/services/$1/routes \
    --data protocols=grpc \
    --data name=$1-grpc \
    --data paths=$2          -----> This line '/'is understood wrong in Git Bash Windows
  printf "\n"
}

SERVICE_NAME=auth
SERVICE_PATH=/com.bht.saigonparking.api.grpc.auth.AuthService/     ----------> path with '/' here

registerServiceRoute ${SERVICE_NAME} ${SERVICE_PATH}
```

As soon as I run the script on Git Bash on Windows,
The console tell that Paths should start with /, 
which means it confuse with / in the path. although / is already correct.

Here is the git bash Windows console output:

```
Register auth service route
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   248  100   143  100   105    674    495 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1169{"message":"schema violation (paths.1: should start with: \/)","name":"schema violation","fields":{"paths":["should start with: \/"]},"code":2}
```

How can I execute script with command have '/' on Git Bash Windows ?

I am looking forward to hearing from you all ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following before your `curl` command:

```
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
```

Caveat emptor: The solution is based off a similar issue that occurs for docker commands on Windows (ref: [The DevOps 2.1 Toolkit: Docker Swarm](https://books.google.com/books?id=hHc5DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA196&lpg=PA196&dq=environment+variable+windows+MSYS_NO_PATHCONV&source=bl&ots=9AW2uHiBQ7&sig=ACfU3U1kwtYXN9LqmM5Cy2P_2W5zc9-bLw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN-vG-gsLpAhUQo54KHVCCCaAQ6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false))